# How can I filter an array based on values ​from other arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a problem with filtering the data array.

I have three arrays:

`permissions:[]` - The array has a list of permissions, that is:
permission_id,name. It contains all permissions. For example:

```
permissions:[{permission_id: 1, name: XXX}, {permission_id: 2, name: XXX}]
```

Another array of data is roles, which includes all roles:

```
roles:[{role_id: 1, role_name: XXX}, {role_id: 2, role_name: XXX}]
```

And the last table contains the links between the roles and their permissions, that is:

```
permissionsAndRoles:[{id: 1, role_id: 1,permission_id:1}, {id:2, role_id: 2, permissions_id: 2},{id:3, role_id: 1, permissions_id: 2}]
```

What I would like to accomplish is to get an array of permissions which, after filtering, will only contain permissions that a given role does not have.
For example:

```
filteredArray(permissions,roles,permissionsAndRoles,role_id){
//input role_id=2
//output:permissions:[{permission_id: 1, name:XXX}]

}
```

What i have tried:

```
fileteredArray: function(){
      return this.permissions.filter(
        permission => this.permissionsAndRoles.some(
          obj => this.roles.some(role=>)
        )
      )
```

And here I am, because I don't know how well to put together the whole logic of this filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need roles array in this case

Live Demo

```js
const permissions = [{ permission_id: 1, name: 'p-111' }, { permission_id: 2, name: 'p-222' }];
// const roles = [{ role_id: 1, role_name: 'r-111' }, { role_id: 2, role_name: 'r-222' }];
const permissionsAndRoles = [{ id: 1, role_id: 1, permission_id: 1 }, { id:2, role_id: 2, permissions_id: 2 },{ id:3, role_id: 1, permissions_id: 2 }];

const hasNotPermissionsByRole = (permissionsAndRoles, permissions, targetRoleId) => {
  const permissionsByRole = permissionsAndRoles
    .filter(({ role_id }) => role_id === targetRoleId )
    .map(({ permissions_id }) => permissions_id);
    
  return permissions
    .filter(({ permission_id }) => !permissionsByRole.includes(permission_id));
};

const targetRoleId = 2;
console.log(hasNotPermissionsByRole(permissionsAndRoles, permissions, targetRoleId));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: Not working for me, it shows all permissions instead of filtered permissions

Comment: @zirson Can you edit post and provide actual data, condition and expected result please?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You want to get the filtered permissions which does not match with the permissions assigned to the roles in `permissionsAndRoles` array. If Yes, You can simply achieve it with the help of [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method along with [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Live Demo **:**

```js
const permissions = [{permission_id: 1, name: 'XXX'}, {permission_id: 2, name: 'XXX'}];

const roles = [{role_id: 1, role_name: 'XXX'}, {role_id: 2, role_name: 'XXX'}];

const permissionsAndRoles = [{id: 1, role_id: 1, permission_id:1}, {id:2, role_id: 2, permission_id: 2},{id:3, role_id: 1, permission_id: 2}];

function filteredArray(roleId) {
  const filteredPermissionAndRoles = permissionsAndRoles.filter(({ role_id }) => role_id === roleId).map(obj => obj.permission_id);
  const filteredPermissions = permissions.filter(({ permission_id }) => !filteredPermissionAndRoles.includes(permission_id));
  return filteredPermissions;
}

const res = filteredArray(2);

console.log(res);
```